# Using mixins in class based view - Django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

So I started using the generic class based views and I gotta say, they do save time. But I was wondering whether I could use mixins to provide generic impl rather than having to code in each view. for e.g.
I have a `ListView` and `DetailView`. To restrict the listing and editing, I could override the `get_queryset()` and filter it by the logged in user. But as you guessed, i would have to do that in each view,

```
class JediListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        q = <call super>.filter(user=request.user) #assume i have 'login_required' in the urls

class JediDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        q = <call super>.filter(user=request.user) #assume i have 'login_required' in the urls
```

I could create a new parent class for each of the view but I would still be repeating the code.

```
class RepublicListView(ListView):
     # override get_queryset code as above

class JediListView(RepublicListView):

# repeat fot DetailView, DeleteView, UpdateView
```

I was wondering about mixins, I am exactly sure how mixins work [from java background, so I am awed and fearful at the same time]

Comment: can somebody edit this question, it is not clear to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You actually almost found the answer by yourself. You can write the following Mixin:

```
class UserFilterMixin:
    def get_queryset(self):
        return <call super>.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

And then use it in the classes like this:

```
class RepublicListView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserFilterMixin, ListView):
```

And so on for the other classes...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LoginRequiredMixin` from [django-braces](http://django-braces.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from braces.views import LoginRequiredMixin


class JediListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = JediModel


class JediDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, Detail):
    model = JediModel
```

As per `Chapter-8: Best Practices for Class-Based Views` from [TWO SCOOPS of DJANGO](http://django.2scoops.org/),

> **THIRD-PARTY PACKAGES:** CBVs + django-braces Are Great Together We feel
>   that django-braces is the missing component for Django CBVs. It
>   provides a set of clearly coded mixins that make Django CBVs much
>   easier and faster to implement. !e next few chapter will demonstrate
>   it's mixins in various code examples.

Comment: That is actually not an answer for the question above.

Comment: True, it was a mistake on my part. I should have defined an `UserFilterMixin` like you did for filtering queryset for current user.